# Сохранить изображение выбранное из галереи

Tags: java, android, изображения, gallery

Как я могу сохранить изображение выбранное из галереи по такому же принципу

```
@SuppressLint("QueryPermissionsNeeded")
public void createPhoto() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createPhotoFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (photoFile != null) {
            Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(activity,
                    "com.example.notes.android.fileprovider",
                    photoFile);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
            activity.startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
        }
    }
}

public File createPhotoFile() throws IOException {
    File image = File.createTempFile(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()), ".jpg", storageDir);
    setPhotoPath(image.getAbsolutePath());
    return image;
}
```

Фотографии сделанные на фотокамеру сохраняются отлично, не получается так же сохранить картинку из галереи

```
@SuppressLint("QueryPermissionsNeeded")
public void createImage() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    if (intent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
        activity.startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_SELECT_IMAGE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для сохранения изображения используйте метод

```
private fun saveImage(image: Bitmap): String? {
        var savedImagePath: String? = null
        val imageFileName = "JPEG_" + "FILE_NAME" + ".jpg"
        val storageDir = File(
            Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
                .toString() + "/YOUR_FOLDER_NAME"
        )
        var success = true
        if (!storageDir.exists()) {
            success = storageDir.mkdirs()
        }
        if (success) {
            val imageFile = File(storageDir, imageFileName)
            savedImagePath = imageFile.getAbsolutePath()
            try {
                val fOut: OutputStream = FileOutputStream(imageFile)
                image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fOut)
                fOut.close()
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }


            galleryAddPic(savedImagePath)
        }
        return savedImagePath
    }
```

Для сохранения изображения по url, нужно сначала нужно получить bitmap данного изображения. Попробуйте использовать Glide.

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
```

Метод получения bitmap

```
private fun getImageFrom(url: String): Bitmap? {
    return Glide.with(context)
            .asBitmap()
            .load(url)
            .placeholder(android.R.drawable.progress_indeterminate_horizontal) // любое изображение
            .error(android.R.drawable.stat_notify_error) // любое изображение
            .submit()
            .get()
    }
```

Подробнее:

*https://github.com/bumptech/glide*

Answer (score 2):

Сохранить изображение можно так

```
private void SavePicture(ImageView iv) {
    OutputStream fOut = null;
    try {
        File file = new File("/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/______/background.jpg"); // создать уникальное имя для файла основываясь на дате сохранения
        fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);

        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)iv.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, fOut); // сохранять картинку в jpeg-формате с 85% сжатия.
        fOut.flush();
        fOut.close();
        MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getActivity().getContentResolver(), file.getAbsolutePath(), file.getName(),  file.getName()); // регистрация в фотоальбоме
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Подскажите, а как можно сохранить изображение в свою папку по полученной ссылке на изображение?